# The right way to calculate the volume obtained by rotating the area between 2 graphs around the x axis

Tags: calculus, integration

If i have 2 graphs: $f(x)=x\cdot \frac{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}{2},\:g(x)=\frac{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}{2}$

And need to calculate the volume obtained by rotating the area between $f(x)$ and $g(x)$

Around the $x$-axis.

I know i need to compute the integral: $\pi \int_{-1}^{1}(g^{2}(x)-f^{2}(x))$

But can i do that direct or do i need to calculate: $\pi( \int_{-1}^{0}(g^{2}(x)-f^{2}(x))+\int_{0}^{1}(g^{2}(x)-f^{2}(x)))$?

Because it doesn't give the same result.

Thanks.

Comment: It should give the same result. Even better, take advantage of symmetry, integrate from $0$ to $1$, and double.

Comment: @AndréNicolas - i didn't get the same result from $-1$ to $0$ and from $0$ to $1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have concerns, we do the calculation. We have $g^2(x)=\frac{1-x^2}{4}$ and $f^2(x)=\frac{x^2(1-x^2)}{4}$, and therefore the difference is $\frac{(1-x^2)^2}{4}$, which is $\frac{1}{4}(1-2x^2+x^4)$. Integrate from $0$ to $1$. An antiderivative is $\frac{1}{4}(x-\frac{2}{3}x^3+\frac{1}{5}x^5)$.

Do the substitution. We get $\frac{1}{4}\left(1-\frac{2}{3}+\frac{1}{5}\right)$, which should be $\frac{2}{15}$.

To integrate from $-1$ to $0$, we again need to substitute. We get $-\frac{1}{4}\left(-1+\frac{2}{3}-\frac{1}{5}\right)$, the same number.

To integrate if we integrate directly from $-1$ to $1$, we get
$$\frac{1}{4}\left(-1+\frac{2}{3}-\frac{1}{5}\right)-\frac{1}{4}\left(-1+\frac{2}{3}-\frac{1}{5}\right),$$
which is exactly what we get by integrating separately and adding.

But there was no need to do the calculation for negative $x$. For our integrand is an **even** function. The integral over any interval $[-a,a]$ is twice the integral from $0$ to $a$.

**Remark:** I would almost automatically note the symmetry, integrate from $0$ to $1$, and double. But I am exceptionally bad at handling negative numbers, and really don't like them. They are so $\dots$ *negative*.

Comment: You are too kind.. about the remark, did you mean: from $-1$ to $0$? otherwise you don't deal with negative.. thanks!

Comment: I added some stuff, doing the two integrals, and also the one in one step. One gets the same answer. The reason you ran into trouble was that having a lot of minus signs around leads to problems, essentially typos, but leading to a wrong answer.

Comment: yes, i can see that now:( thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This description is a bit peculiar because the curve for  $\frac{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}{2}$ lies below the  x-axis for  $-1 ≤ x < 0$  , so its contribution to the volume is lost inside the volume produced by $\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{2}$.  It seems you would use the integral over  $0 ≤ x ≤ 1 $ just as you've written it, but could omit $f(x)$ in the integral for $ -1 ≤ x ≤ 0$ .

The solid looks like the ellipsoid generated by revolving $g(x)$, with a "teardrop"-shaped void in the portion over  $0 ≤ x ≤ 1 $.

Comment: i'm not sure i understand, i can't compute a direct calculation from $-1$ to $1$? and why can i omit $f(x)$? thanks for your answer.

Comment: If you graph the two curves, you'll see that the enclosed area is asymmetrical about the  y-axis, since  $f(x)$ is an odd function, but $g(x)$ is even.  The question I have about this problem is how to count the volume of the "left-hand" portion of $f(x)$, since its revolved volume is completely enclosed within that of $g(x)$.  It seems that the volume for $f(x)$ over $-1 ≤ x ≤ 0$ is being "double-counted" as things stand.